# Proper way to create a pivot table with crosstab

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, case, crosstab

How do I convert the following query into a pivot table using crosstab?

```
select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_customer=false
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
        END)) AS CUSTOMERS_NOT_ADDED, (SUM(CASE WHEN added_customer=true
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
        END)) AS CUSTOMERS_ADDED, 

        (select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_sales_order=false
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
                END))  
        FROM shipments_data
        ) AS SALES_ORDER_NOT_ADDED, 

        (select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_sales_order=true
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
                END))  
        FROM shipments_data
        ) AS SALES_ORDER_ADDED,


        (select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_fulfillment=false
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
                END))  
        FROM shipments_data
        ) AS ITEM_FULFILLMENT_NOT_ADDED, 

        (select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_fulfillment=true
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
                END))  
        FROM shipments_data
        ) AS ITEM_FULFILLMENT_ADDED,


        (select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_invoice=false
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
                END))  
        FROM shipments_data
        ) AS INVOICE_NOT_ADDED, 

        (select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_invoice=true
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
                END))  
        FROM shipments_data
        ) AS INVOICE_ADDED,

        (select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_ra=false
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
                END))  
        FROM shipments_data
        ) AS RA_NOT_ADDED, 

        (select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_ra=true
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
                END))  
        FROM shipments_data
        ) AS RA_ADDED,

        (select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_credit_memo=false
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
                END))  
        FROM shipments_data
        ) AS CREDIT_MEMO_NOT_ADDED, 

        (select (SUM(CASE WHEN added_credit_memo=true
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
                END))  
        FROM shipments_data
        ) AS CREDIT_MEMO_ADDED

FROM shipments_data;
```

This query gives me data in a standard row format however I would like to show this as a pivot table in the following format:

```
                    Added    Not_Added
Customers             100            0
Sales Orders           50           50
Item Fulfillemnts       0          100
Invoices                0          100
...
```

I am using Heroku PostgreSQL, which is running v9.1.6

Also, I'm not sure if my above query can be optimized or if this is poor form. If it can be optimized/improved I would love to learn how.

Comment: The [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) module that supplies `crosstab()` is available for 9.1 (like for any other version this side of the millennium). Doesn't Heroku let you install additional modules? Have you tried [`CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createextension.html)?

Comment: I haven't tried that - I'll post back with results in a few mins.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter extension installed properly, thanks.

Comment: So I made it into an answer and added a bit to it.

Comment: You may be interested in the additional solution appended to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) module that supplies `crosstab()` is available for 9.1 (like for any other version this side of the millennium). Doesn't Heroku let you install additional modules? Have you tried:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

For examples how to use it, refer to [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) or this related question:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3002499/939860)

OR [try this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crosstab+postgresql) - there are a couple of good answers with examples on SO.

To get you started (like most of the way ..) use this largely simplified and re-organized query as base for the `crosstab()` call:

```
SELECT 'added'::text AS col
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN added_customer    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS customers
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN added_sales_order THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sales_order
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN added_fulfillment THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS item_fulfillment
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN added_invoice     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS invoice
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN added_ra          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ra
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN added_credit_memo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS credit_memo
FROM   shipments_data

UNION ALL
SELECT 'not_added' AS col
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN NOT added_customer    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS customers
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN NOT added_sales_order THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sales_order
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN NOT added_fulfillment THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS item_fulfillment
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN NOT added_invoice     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS invoice
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN NOT added_ra          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ra
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN NOT added_credit_memo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS credit_memo
FROM   shipments_data;
```

If your columns are defined `NOT NULL`, you can further simplify the `CASE` expressions.

If **performance** is crucial, you can get all aggregates *in a single scan in a CTE* and split values into two rows in the next step.

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT count(NULLIF(added_customer, FALSE)) AS customers
         ,sum(added_sales_order::int)          AS sales_order
          ...
         ,count(NULLIF(added_customer, TRUE))  AS not_customers
         ,sum((NOT added_sales_order)::int)    AS not_sales_order
          ...
   FROM   shipments_data
   )
SELECT 'added'::text AS col, customers, sales_order, ... FROM x
UNION  ALL
SELECT 'not_added', not_customers, not_sales_order, ...  FROM x;
```

I also demonstrate two alternative ways to build your aggregates - both built on the assumption that all columns are **`boolean NOT NULL`**. Both alternatives are syntactically shorter, but not faster. In previous testes all three methods performed about the same.